# clearButton not working in UITextEditField

Tags: ios, uitextfield

This is one of those "it was working a while ago" troubleshooting efforts.

I'm working on the document preview view controller, in which is a scroll view, which itself contains subclasses of UIView that represent each document.  I'm modeling this pretty closely to how Keynote handles its document preview, except I build my scroll view horizontally and with paging.  But the standard user experience is present: Long press on a document icon causes all document icons to start jiggling, nab bar has + button and Edit button, etc.

The issue at hand is that when you tap on the name of a document, I hide all the others, move the one being edited front and center, build a new text edit field, add it as a subview atop the real name label, and set it as first responder; but the

```
     [editNameTextField setClearButtonMode:UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing];
```

while correctly showing in the edit field is not taking any action when the user taps on the clear button.

I can't figure out what I may have done to cause this to not work -- it had been!

My first thought was that somehow my instance of this subclass is no longer the delegate for this text edit field.  To try and confirm/deny that, I usurped a tap on the image view of the document preview to compare the delegate property to self, and it passes.

```
if (editNameTextField) {
    NSLog(@"editNameTextField is still active");
    if ([editNameTextField.delegate isEqual:self]) {
        NSLog(@"we're still the delegate for the editNameTextField");
    }
}
```

Editing the text within the edit field works fine.  Pressing the Return/Done key correctly sends the delegate message `textFieldShouldReturn:`

While investigating this I implemented the delegate method `textFieldShouldClear:` just to write a log message if the method gets called (and return YES of course).  It never gets called.

My next thought was that perhaps a subview had covered up the area where the clear button sits.  So I implemented `textFieldShouldBeginEditing:` and used the opportunity to bring my the text field to the front.  That didn't change anything either.  I set a debugger breakpoint there to play a sound when it was called, and it got called, so I know my text edit field is frontmost.

I have only one troubleshooting strategy remaining: Go backwards through snap shots until it starts working again.  Before doing that I thought I'd see if any of the more experienced folks out here have any suggestions of what to try next.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where are you adding the textfield? As a subview of the scrollView? If you added the textfield and it is out of bounds of its parent view it won't receive any touches.

You can try and not call becomeFirstResponder and see if clicking it will show keyboard. Another possible error might be that the parent view of the UITextField has userInteractionEnabled = NO.

Without seeing more code I'm afraid I can not offer more solutions.

Comment: Thanks @LocoMike.  Your comment that it being out of bounds of the parent view is pertinent: My textfield is wider than the parent view, and sure enough, pressing on text within the width of the parent view is doing the normal iOS UI thing of popping up the magnifying glass and letting you precisely place your editing cursor, but finger pressing outside the width of the parent view is ignored.

Comment: Glad to help. When debugging, I usually give views bg colors (red, blue, green...) to have a better feeling of how are the views laid out.

Comment: After hours of searching finally found the correct answer! THANKS!